# my load image function is not working has it got something to do with my try?

Tags: try-catch, pygame

i am trying to create a function to load my images but every time i run it it returns "cannot load image"

```
def load_image(file_name, colorkey = None):

  full_name = os.path.join('data', file_name)

  try:
    image = pygame.image.load(full_name)
 except pygame.error, message:
    print 'Cannot load image:', full_name
    raise SystemExit, message

    image = image.convert()

  if colorkey is not None:
   if colorkey is -1:
    colorkey = image.get_at((0,0))
    image.set_colorkey(colorkey, RLEACCEL)

  return image,image.get()
```

Comment: See my solution.  The issue is that on windows it assumes you are in `the current directory`

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows you will need to do something like this:

```
os.path.join('c:%s' % os.sep, 'data')
```